# Using gsub function

Tags: r, regex

I have a factor that has many levels and  I want to instert a colon between the digits in all my data and I do not how to use gsub function for this.
Example the data I have look like this:

```
ABCD*0801
ABCD*0701
ABCD*0902
ABCD*0311
ABCD*2001
```

and what I want is this :

```
ABCD*08:01
ABCD*07:01
ABCD*09:02
ABCD*03:11
ABCD*20:01
```

I used this code below but I dont understand it

`gsub("(.{4})(.*)$", "\\1:\\2",hladata$DRB1_1)`

can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options with `sub`(since you have just one match per string, `gsub`, which is for multiple matches per string, is not necessary):

```
sub("\\d{2}", "\\1:", x)
```

This works via backreference: the pattern matched in the first argument (the occurrence of two `d`igits) is remembered and repeated in the replacement argument and a `:`is added to it.

```
sub("(?<=\\d{2})(?=\\d{2})", ":", x, perl = TRUE)
```

This, more complex, solution works with lookaround: the lookbehind `(?<=\\d{2})` looks for two digits on the left of the match while `(?=\\d{2})` looks for two digits on the right. Where the two lookarounds match, a `:`is inserted.

The code you used does not work because of the quantifying expression; you need to change it to `{7}` as there are seven characters before the point where you want to insert `:`. The way it works is similar to the second option above, namely via backreference: `\\1` remembers and repeats the first seven characters captured in the first capturing group `(...)` while the second backreference `\\2` remembers and repeats the second capturing group; between them `:` is added.

```
gsub("(.{7})(.*)$", "\\1:\\2", x)
```

Data:

```
x <- as.factor(c("ABCD*0801",
                 "ABCD*0701",
                 "ABCD*0902",
                 "ABCD*0311",
                 "ABCD*2001"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```r
x <- as.factor(c("ABCD*0801",
                 "ABCD*0701",
                 "ABCD*0902",
                 "ABCD*0311",
                 "ABCD*2001"))

as.factor(gsub("(\\d{2}$)",":\\1", x))
#> [1] ABCD*08:01 ABCD*07:01 ABCD*09:02 ABCD*03:11 ABCD*20:01
#> Levels: ABCD*03:11 ABCD*07:01 ABCD*08:01 ABCD*09:02 ABCD*20:01
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As @Roland points out in the comments, it’s more efficient to use `sub` on the factor `levels()`.

```r
x <- as.factor(c("ABCD*0801",
                 "ABCD*0701",
                 "ABCD*0902",
                 "ABCD*0311",
                 "ABCD*2001"))
 
levels(x) <- sub("(\\d{2}$)",":\\1", levels(x))
             
x
#> [1] ABCD*08:01 ABCD*07:01 ABCD*09:02 ABCD*03:11 ABCD*20:01
#> Levels: ABCD*03:11 ABCD*07:01 ABCD*08:01 ABCD*09:02 ABCD*20:01
```

Comment: Use `gsub` on `levels(x)` instead of `x`. That's more efficient.